# TFS binary files three way merge with custom tool

Tags: excel, tfs, merge, three-way-merge, vba

I have a tool for three way merge on VBA code inside Excel workbooks - let's call it XlMerge.
My Excel workbook resides inside TFS.
I hoped that if I add my tool as a user tool it will remove merging headache.
But now TFS doesn't show me "merge with custom tool" button for my xlsb file (binary workbook).
Is there any solutions to make TFS show this button?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the source code setting for the Team Project. Non-text files are considered unmergable by TFS (e.g. a .DLL file), so you may need to make your .xlsb a type of file that's mergeable. Non-mergable files are usually indicated by a lock accompanying an edit check-out automatically.